# Timepicker not updating ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am using a time-picker on certain inputs, The time picker does not update the **ng-model**, I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/extOctyVwTKBMDLB3Nvc?p=preview)

Basically in controller:

```
$('.TimePickers').timepicker();
```

in html:

```
<div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
  <input  ng-model="MonOpen" id="" type="text" class="input-small TimePickers">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
</div>
Model which in not updating: {{MonOpen}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timepicker disconnects the ng-model from your element and therefor changes are not tracked.

For a hacky-solution you could just $compile the element again after the timepicker had its way with it.

Inject `$scope` and `$compile` into your controller and call

`$compile($('.TimePickers'))($scope)`

after you called the `.timepicker` on the element.

```
  app.controller('TimeController', function($compile, $scope){

            $('.TimePickers').timepicker();
            $compile($('.TimePickers'))($scope)
  });
```

Or take a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker for better support of bootstrap-components inside of angular.

Comment: Thank you i'll use the hacky version for now my boss wants me to use this specific javascript timepicker.